# Scale image inside div up AND/OR down to fit largest side of image with CSS

Tags: css, image, web, aspect

I've looked through A LOT of Q&A here on the topic but can't find a definitive answer if one exists.

I have a div of dynamic width and height and want to fit any sized image inside of it and keep the aspect ratio.  This could be scaling the image up or down:

[image: Image scaling scenarios]

I've tried every combo of width, height, max-width,  max-height, Object-fit etc I can think of with no luck, there's always at least one case that fails.  Most solutions I've seen involve some hard coded max-width or height values.  Is it possible to get ALL above cases working only with CSS and a dynamically sized div container?

PS my target browser is Edge if that makes a difference.

THANKS!!

Comment: I added an example of all cases here: https://jsfiddle.net/rambutan2000/8rmvp8a7/

Comment: So I asked this because I'm making a simple slide show, here's an example with everything working (tested in Edge and Chrome) https://jsfiddle.net/rambutan2000/vvsnus6o/

Comment: Here's an example without the background 'hack', partially working in Edge though: https://jsfiddle.net/rambutan2000/tu2ps0go/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Apply the image as an css background using `background: url(path/to/image)` and then using the `background-size` attribute to set the scaling to contain, `background-size: contain` (see fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/mghgsk5e/).

Comment: Option 1 doesn't meet the requirement of scaling UP, only DOWN.

Comment: Thanks Mathias!  I've expanded your example and tested it on Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/rambutan2000/q4kr4z1r/ All cases are working.

Answer (score 1):

For all modern browsers *except* Edge, and all versions of Internet Explorer, you can use the CSS property `object-fit`.

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/09cpe9e0/1/

I would be inclined to implement a javascript solution for Internet Explorer and Edge that can be removed at a later date, leaving only the CSS version when it is safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks Le-roy, just to be 100% clear, there's no way of getting all cases working in CSS without object-fit?

Comment: I wasn't able to come up with anything, nor anyone else I found online. It may be possible to find a non-standard hack but I'd avoid taking that route if possible.